# Seguir usando datos insertados en la basedatos codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Les cuento que estoy trabajando en CodeIgniter estoy haciendo una sola función, lo primero que hago es insertar:

```
$data = array(
  'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
  'opcion' => $this->input->post('opcion'),
  );
```

pregunto como obtengo la var *opcion* para poder seguir usándolo en el php?

*$opcion*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente eso es aparte del framework, estas teniendo problemas con lo basico de PHP, en este caso deberías comprender un poco mejor el manejo y uso de [arreglos](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, solo es cuestion de acceder al arreglo por su indice, por ejemplo:

```
$data = array(
  'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
  'opcion' => $this->input->post('opcion'),
  );

echo $data['opcion'];
```

Te recomiendo revisar los fundamentos del lenguaje.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, estoy aprendiendo asiendo y reconozco que me falta indagar más un poco en la documentación y entender los fundamentos, pero el tiempo es oro y stackoverflow la mejor escuela. Y gracias amigo te la debo.

Comment: De nada, si te sirvio la respuesta considera marcarla como solucion a tu pregunta, de esta manera mejoran las estadisticas del sitio, y otros usuarios pueden encontrar util tu respuesta. Claro para eso está el sitio, para ayudar a la comunidad. Sigue creciendo como desarrollador :)